# 3D object detection from detected 2D bounding box wihout deep learning

Tags: computer-vision, object-detection

I currently can detect the 2D bounding box for objects. Now I want to find the 3D bounding box which is related to the 2D bounding box, but I still do not know how to do it. I did some research on the internet but I am so confused. Can anyone guild me step by step on how to achieve 3D bbx from 2D bbx? Thank you so much. [image: 2D bounding box]

Comment: Could you explain the need to get 3D location, orientation and dimension of objects from single camera image?. You can only approximate 3D bounding boxes from 2D BB.

Comment: @Vinu: yes, how can I approximate the 3D bounding boxes from 2D bbx. because my task is that using the result from 2D objection detection task to compute the object location in 3D relative to the car.